# What is Unique Identification (UID) number of a pointer?

Tags: linux, pointers, linux-kernel

In the book [Linux Kernel Development by Robert Love](https://doc.lagout.org/operating%20system%20/linux/Linux%20Kernel%20Development%2C%203rd%20Edition.pdf), I found the following lines (Pg: 100 - 101).

> The Linux kernel provides a simple and efficient map data structure,
>   but it is not a general-purpose map. Instead, it is designed for one
>   specific use case: mapping a unique identification number (UID) to a
>   pointer.

What does "Unique identification number (UID) to a pointer" mean in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does "Unique identification number (UID) to a pointer" mean in this context?

Nothing. You're parsing the sentence incorrectly.

> The map data structure maps $X to $Y.

$X is "a unique identification number (UID)".

$Y is "a pointer".

In other words, the "map data structure" is a dictionary where the keys are UIDs and the values are pointers.